# Expanding cell to match height of other cell in row

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table row with two cells inside, the height is different because the data inside changes, so I cannot set an explicit height.

The two cells contain div's and are likely to be different heights due to the content inside, my question is is it possible to have a cell take up 100% height so they both cells match?

It's a bit vague in text form, so here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hmH6m/).

The second cell and div should match the height of the first.

Unfortunately I've tried setting the height to 100% without success.

```
td, div {
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Cells' heights are always matched. It is the divs' heights. Just remove the divs or set the background on the td instead(though it will affect all other tds in the table) Check: http://jsfiddle.net/hmH6m/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the 'height:100%' tag, all parents also are required to have a height value set.

For example, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xynariz/MsjLq/):

```
td {
    width:100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
table, tr, td{
    height: 100%;
}

td div {
    background-color:grey;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Blast IE and its nonconformity.

Answer (score 0):

can't you put background color in the TD??

But if you want div to expand, you can do this

> div {
>   background-color: grey;
>   display: inline-block;
>   height: 100%; 
>   }